# Error when running database script Report Server Configuration Manager

Tags: configuration, reportserver, ssrs-2019

I am trying to configure a Report Server Database in the Report Server Configuration Manager and I get the error when it gets to the running database script. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHtRo.png)

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The object 'classified' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
The object 'classified' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
The object 'classified' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
The object 'classified' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
The object 'classified' is dependent on database collation. The database collation cannot be changed if a schema-bound object depends on it. Remove the dependencies on the database collation and then retry the operation.
CREATE DATABASE failed. The default collation of database 'ReportServer' cannot be set to 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_KS_WS'.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Common.DBUtils.ApplyScript(SqlConnection conn, String script, ICommandWrapperFactory commandWrapper)
at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Common.DBUtils.ApplyScript(String connectionString, String script)
at ReportServicesConfigUI.SqlClientTools.SqlTools.ApplyScript(String connectionString, String script)

```
Can anyone help, please?
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
It turned out that we put some stored procedures and functions in the Model database, which is used as the template when SQL Server creates a new database, and those objects were preventing the server from changing the collation of the new database.